# Insert Line Breaks between form response values in email

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to insert line breaks or carriage returns after each selection sent from a form. So I start with a Google Form sending data to a Google Sheet when the trigger activates the script to email the form data.

```
function myfunction(e){
  var formAuthor = e.values[1];
  var market = e.values[2];
  var address = e.values[3];
  var ticket = e.values[4];
  var userName = e.values[5];
  var phone = e.values[6];
  var comment = e.values[7];
  var subject = "Dispatch Request " + market;
  var message = market + address + ticket + userName + phone + comment;

  MailApp.sendEmail("myemail@myemail.nothing", subject, message);
}
```

Here is the output:

BP123321Bob1231234567stuff n things

Here is what I would like to see:

```
BP
123
321
Bob
1231234567
stuff n things
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var message = [
  market,
  address,
  ticket,
  userName,
  phone,
  comment].join("\n")
```

Comment: Thank you, so simple of a fix!

Comment: Could have replaced all the `var` lines as well with just: `var message = e.values.join("\n");`.